# Show that a equivelance relation implies a natural injection

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am struggling with grasping the concept of how equivelance relations can imply injective (or any type) of mapping. My problem is:

Consider the following equivelance relation on $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}^*$

$$(x,y)R(x',y')\Leftrightarrow x'y=y'x$$

Show that there is a natural injection:

$$i:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\frac{\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}^*}{R}$$

Can anyone give me a few pointers on how to get started?

Comment: Did you realize that $\frac{\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z^*}{R}$ is $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: How exactly is it Q?

Comment: ahh...becuase x'y=y'x which imples x/x'=y/y'?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: ahh ok, So I just have to show that there is a natural injection i: Z -->Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $i$ be defined by

$$i(n) = [n, 1] \in \frac{\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z^*}{R}$$

(This is just the natural inclusion $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Q$). To show that it is injective, let $n, m\in \mathbb Z$ so that $i(n)=i(m)$. Then

$$[n, 1] = [m,1]\Rightarrow n\times 1 = m\times 1 \Rightarrow m=n.$$

Thus $i$ is injective.